# How to print all array using SQL statement inside the PHP Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, laravel

I have one input which is policy_no variables at the view blades. The user will insert many policy_no in one input. So, I have separate all input at the controller because it consist of space between each policy_no. When all policy_no is being separated, it will be check inside the sql statement whether those policy_no is exist or not?

When I `dd($policyNumbers[$y]);`
Output : 790618146087-1902 790618146087-1903

But when I put it inside the sql statement, the value that will be print is 790618146087-1903

Currently, how can I check the policy_no one by one? I already create for loop. But still the for loop doesn't loop as I wanted. Did I miss anything?

Controller :

```
        $policyNumbers = preg_split ('/\n/', $request->policy_no);
        $countPolicy = count($policyNumbers);

        for ($x = $countPolicy; $x >= 0; $x--) {
                $y = $x - 1;

                if($y >= 0){
                    //dd($policyNumbers[$y]);
                    $item = InsuranceEnrollment::select('policy_no')->where('policy_no','=',$policyNumbers[$y])->get();
                    dd($item);

                }else{
                    echo("try");
                }
        }
```

view.blade

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label>Policy No</label>
                    <textarea name="policy_no" value="$items->policy_no" type="text" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$item = InsuranceEnrollment::select('policy_no')>whereIn('policy_no',$policyNumbers)->get();
dd($item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this It will help to you.
If `$policyNumbers = preg_split ('/\n/', $request->policy_no);`  is in array than it will help to you.

```
$policyNumbers = preg_split ('/\n/', $request->policy_no);
$countPolicy = count($policyNumbers);

$item = InsuranceEnrollment::select('policy_no')->$query->whereIn('policy_no',$policyNumbers)->get();
dd($item);
```